# Paypal rest sdk does successful transaction but with no history of it on sandbox

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working on this sdk for paypal here and I'm running into a bunch of errors like: "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@paypal.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log"

when everything seems to go right, I get transferred to the /success with all the payment json back. the problem is that the console.log("payerId = " + payerId) never logs and when i log into my sandbox I have no history of any transaction even though I went though the motions of one. I get no error back so idk what I am doing wrong. THX!

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path')
let port = 5007;
let app = express();
// const ejs = require('ejs');
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
// const Paypal = require('./Server/Paypal_api.js')
// const Nodemailer = require('./Server/Nodemailer.js')

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// app.use(express.static('assets'))
// app.use(cors())
// app.use(bodyParser.json())

paypal.configure({
    'mode': 'sandbox', //sandbox or live
    'client_id': 'AYoej9yvsPTO_giNMnI5pMecd4vbelcK_N',  
    'client_secret': 'EE8rJValbapV4Dk-g5yFFMG7pMC-bwwwv7sO'
});
```

client id & secret not real but you get it

```
app.post('/pay', (req, res) => {
    const create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Red Sox Hat",
                "sku": "001",
                "price": "25.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "25.00"
        },
        "description": "Hat for the best team ever"
    }]
};

paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, (error, payment) =>{
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        // console.log(payment)
        for(let i = 0;i < payment.links.length;i++){
        if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url'){
            res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
        }
        }
    }
});

});

app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
    const payerId = req.query.PayerID;
    const paymentId = req.query.paymentId;
    console.log("payerId = " + payerId)

    const execute_payment_json = {
    "payer_id": payerId,
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "25.00"
        }
    }]
    };

    paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, (error, payment) =>{
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
        res.send('Success');
    }
});
});

app.get('/cancel', (req, res) => res.send('Cancelled'));




app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("resonating on port " + port)
})
```